# XAF send server side values before client side execute save command

Tags: c#, inline, aspxgridview, xaf

I have problem when press inline save action without leaving last edited cell,
application didn't sent callback before saving to take last changes.

Steps
1- Open any header record for edit[image]
2- Add new detail record by pressing inline new action,
then change val 1 to 10, if you leave the cell app will send call back to server side
to update val 2 and 3 by code executed on event OnChanged in detail class,
this is the expected behavior, the problem happened when you press save action without
leaving the cell to execute the callback
[image]

I think the solution should be manually perform callback and update client side with the new value before execute saving, but i don't know how to do it.

Can you help me find a global solutions for all grid in the application.

[Download Test Solution Files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cTEa4PrtWl13uxrSNsjgEnRr7r0gZGjd/view?usp=sharing)

Cheers,
Omar